# How to get the number of words given as input in a "read" command?

Tags: linux, read

For the following command, how to know, how many words are given in the input?

```
$ read text
```

I would like to take a new variable which will count the number of words given input to "text". As for example if,

```
$ read text
apple
```

The variable, if that is x, will get a value of '1'

and for the following,

```
$read text
apple banana
```

'x' will get a value of 2.

Answer (score 3):

There's the immediate bash option as well, using the `-a` option to `read`:

```
read -a text
echo "The input '${text[@]}' contains ${#text[@]} words."
```

With the `-a` option, the variable is an array of words obtained using the usual, IFS separator. See `man bash`, under BUILTIN COMMANDS, for more details.

Comment: That is rather twisted. I like it. [I would probably use wc(1), though.]

Comment: Note that by that count, `foo\ bar` is one word.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one more way to do it -- read the variable as you already have, then use the POSIX-standard [`set`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) utility along with the shell's standard variable expansion mechanism, then assign the resulting number of elements to `x`:

```
read text
set -f        ## disable filename generation ("globbing")
set -- $text
x=$#
```

Comment: Excellent point; I've updated the answer. Thanks, @Kusalananda!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wc -w` to count words. (Please have a look at `man wc`.)

```
$ read text
apple banana
$ echo $text
apple banana
$ echo $text|wc -w
2
$ x=$(echo $text|wc -w)
$ echo $x
2
$ echo "The input '$text' contains $x words."
The input 'apple banana' contains 2 words.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get o after putting $ echo $x